# Decorators in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
function debounce(f, ms) {
  let isCool = false;

  return function() {
    if (!isCool) {
      f.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    isCool = true;
    setTimeout(() => isCool = false, ms);
  };
}


let f = debounce(alert, 1000);

f(1); // runs immediately
f(2); // ignored


setTimeout(() => f(3), 100); // ignored ( only 100 ms passed )
setTimeout(() => f(4), 1100); // runs
setTimeout(() => f(5), 1500); // ignored (less than 1000 ms from the last run)
```

The result of debounce(f, ms) decorator should be a wrapper that passes the call to f at maximum once per ms milliseconds. When we call a “debounced” function, it guarantees that all future calls to the function made less than ms milliseconds after the previous call will be ignored. 
  Why my code doesn't working as it should be? It should ignore call to f(5), instead it runs...

Comment: `isCool = false` is set 1000ms after *every* call to `f`, regardless of whether it was a debounced call or not. Even `f(2)` sets up a timer to clear `isCool` 1000ms later…

Comment: return function() { if (isCool) return ......

Answer (score 1):

@deceze's comment answers your question. I'll add that there's no reason to complicate matters with `setTimeout`.  Simply track time between invocations.

```js
function debounce(f, ms) {
  let lastApply = 0;
  const cooldownMs = ms;
  return function() {
    let now = Date.now();
    if ((now - cooldownMs) >= lastApply) {
      lastApply = now;
      f.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  };
}


let f = debounce(console.log, 1000);

f(1); // runs immediately
f(2); // ignored


setTimeout(() => f(3), 100); // ignored ( only 100 ms passed )
setTimeout(() => f(4), 1100); // runs
setTimeout(() => f(5), 1500); // ignored (less than 1000 ms from the last run)
```

Comment: Then another question. Why when we use `console.log` - everything is fine, and when alert - result is different?

Comment: @Roman because `debounce` is strictly concerned with *time* which never stops its dreadful march forward - even for a time consuming `alert`.

Comment: I see). But could you explain to me this: does all the ms in calls after f(2) have matters? I mean that in the line `let f = debounce(console.log, 1000);` this 1000ms always will be execute or after first call and time passing delaying is set to another ms? I know, the formulation of this question is not perfect, I hope you can understand)

Comment: @Roman I'm not exactly clear on your question.  `f` constructs the function's cool down `lastApply` according to the paramter `ms`which value is assigned to the constant `cooldownMs`.  Calls to `f(x)` in `setTimeout` are ordered by its delay in milliseconds parameter, not call order.

Comment: @ RamblinRose `function debounce(f, ms) {

  let isCooldown = false;

  return function() {
    if (isCooldown) return;

    f.apply(this, arguments);

    isCooldown = true;

    setTimeout(() => isCooldown = false, ms);
  };

}` I know, I'm annoying you with this task, but could you be so kind explain to me why this variant works, and mine - nope (mine in the question post). They almost the same except for if statement...

Comment: @ RamblinRose Is it because of return statement?

Comment: @Roman, yes in the sense your effect on the state of the function is not scoped properly. See @deceze's comment again.  I posted here to illustrate no need for the use of `setTimeout` which IMO makes the code a bit more difficult to grok. Your code will work modified as so `if (!isCool) {
      isCool = true;
      setTimeout(() => isCool = false, ms);
      f.apply(this, arguments);
    } `